# Android Studio Emulator 2.0 support for older versions glitch

Tags: android-emulator

I tested the new Android Studio 2.0 Emulator and they improved its performance. However, when i create an AVD with older android versions (Gingerbread, IceCream Sandwich) and i run it, the emulator shows glitchy 4 screens instead of one. The result is showed in this screenshot:
[Emulator Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynAK4.png)